# Outsystems: How to pass JSON object/string as HTTP header in consuming REST API

Tags: json, outsystems

I am trying to consume a publicly exposed URL and I need to pass auth headers to it. The format of the HTTP header is :

```
auth:{"Username": "p09jh789-f098-h6fv-b386-008cd88bd4fe","Password": "xxxxxxxx","authKey": "62b6380d-9e06-6age-cf09-134614b77d5e"}
```

I tried to set auth header for the REST API and I am not able to pass this JSON string since text headers throw up datatype issue. This happens even if I try to escape the JSON string. Please help me with doing it.

Comment: You can customize the request by adding the 'OnBeforeRequest' action on the consumed API. Here you should be able to set the customised header values.

Comment: But that doesn't allow me to set a header value to be a JSON object :(

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *throw up the datatype issue*. HTTP Headers are always plain text. Any other format you want to send in a HTTP header needs to be converted to a plain text string beforehand.

Comment: Can you perhaps share the URI of the API you are consuming so that we can help you test?

Comment: [When right-clicking the consumer RESTful Api you can add the parameters here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhiZF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Send each value as a different header item. And validate each item in the `OnBeforeRequest`.